# How is Facebook's website front-end and it's right sidebar designed?

Tags: css, html, design-patterns

I am wondering how Facebook front-end is designed, especially it's fixed right sidebar? I would like to implement similar sidebar in my web app to display user's tasks. But I would first like to understand better how Facebook's sidebar work.

First thing I would like to understand is how they handle that the right sidebar is always there! It is not reloading when you open new link inside facebook. I understand the visual CSS part, no problems there: `position:fixed; right:0; top:0; height:100%;`. But I really wonder how they do this: when you click a link inside Facebook that loads a new page (e.g. clicking a friend's name) then the entire new page content is loaded, but it doesn't seem that sidebar is loaded again. It just sits there all the time.

They don't do any AJAX stuff when you click the link, so the content of the entire page doesn't load via AJAX? Is it just so damn fast or they use some kind of (to me unknown) design pattern?

Comment: I think [this article on BigPipe](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=389414033919) answers the question (at least at a high level).

Comment: Wow very interesting read. So this BigPipe actually does this: 1. When server receives a page request it sends out a response with simple html template describing page chunks and a JS library, 2. Initiate JS to scan the template and start multiple AJAX request to fetch HTML, CSS and JS for different page chunks, 3. Browser then renders the responses from each page chunk request... That is more or less it?

Comment: That sounds correct; theoretically the simple HTML template would render very quickly and the unchanged chunks could use data that was already available to the browser (e.g. local storage). But there might be more to it (it's a good question).

Comment: I searched if there are any open source implementations (in PHP and JS) of this design pattern, but I could only found some outdated experiments, mostly this one https://github.com/garo/bigpipe. Very little actually. I guess this is something that could easily be implemented in most MVC PHP frameworks like FuelPHP, Zend, Laravel, ...

Comment: There is another thing that got added later: Manipulating the URL with the [history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) (see pushState/popState). The sidebar doesn't reload because the page doesn't reload - but the URL still changes.

Comment: @kapep it doesn't look they are manipulating with the history api... they are making request to the actual URI's from which they built the page... Maybe for some things yes but as far as I managed to debug it not!

Comment: @PrimozRome I just checked it again, (at least for me) they do use it almost everywhere. Maybe it's not active for every browser but I can certainly see it in firefox. When clicking a link, there aren't any request to the link's url, just an ajax get request to `https://www.facebook.com/ajax/home/generic.php?ajaxpipe=1& ...` containing parts of the original url as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody wants to answer this I think I can provide the answer which helped me answered my question most accurate.

The answer is in this [Facebook's dev blog post](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=389414033919), which describe **BigPipe design pattern** pioneered by Facebook. BigPipe separates page into different chunks called 'pagelets' and loads  them asynchronously (in parallel).

I found an [open source PHP implementation](https://github.com/garo/bigpipe) of BigPipe and [live example here](http://www.juhonkoti.net/bigpipe/example.php) but it is long since it's been updated and doesn't look to be in active development.